# Redux Saga Firebase - When to use firestore.channel() versus firestore.syncCollection()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm building an react native application with Redux Saga Firebase and can't seem to figure out the difference/when to use `firestore.channel()` versus `firestore.syncCollection()`.

**Documentation Links:**

- [firestore.channel(pathOrRef, type, buffer)](https://redux-saga-firebase.js.org/reference/dev/firestore#syncCollection)
- [firestore.syncCollection(pathOrRef, options)](http://firestore.syncCollection(pathOrRef,%20options))

**What I'm trying to build:**

I'm building an app where users can see posts, so I've got a posts collection /posts in Cloud Firestore. When a user submits an new post to that collection, I want every user on the app to automatically receive the post in their posts feed.

**My Thoughts:**

- Would firestore.channel() be the best way to go about solving this? Would a channel automatically show posts in every users post feed?
- It seems like firestore.syncCollection() generator would be called to
  sync the collection on a pull to refresh type of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The `channel` is just a lower-level saga construct than `syncCollection`. They both emit data in the same circumstances based on the `pathOrRef` argument, but with `syncCollection` a redux action is dispatched, whereas `channel` creates a lower-level redux-saga `channel` which you can `take` events from and decide how you want to handle them - that could be `put`ing redux actions or responding in some other way.

If you just need to dispatch the same redux action whenever your firestore data changes, use `syncCollection`, if you have some more complicated logic or want to respond with something other than a redux action, use `channel`.

You can read more about channels and how to use them here: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html